# How do I parse a page with html5ever and find all the links?

Tags: web-scraping, rust, html5ever

I would like to parse HTML in the string format with html5ever and find all the links in this HTML. I'm aware of [How do I parse a page with html5ever, modify the DOM, and serialize it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38859811/how-do-i-parse-a-page-with-html5ever-modify-the-dom-and-serialize-it), however `RcDom` does not exist anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a struct which implements `TokenSink`, then create a new `Tokenizer` where your struct is the `sink`. When parsing with `Tokenizer::feed()`, it will pass all tokens through your `TokenSink`.

This code was adapted from the [html5ever examples](https://github.com/servo/html5ever/blob/master/html5ever/examples/tokenize.rs), so it is Apache/MIT licensed. html5ever is a complicated library built for browsers, and it shows - the API appears to be designed to accommodate encodings other than UTF-8.

This code only parses from stdin. If you want to use it as is, pipe `curl` like so `curl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59461279/how-do-i-parse-a-page-with-html5ever-and-find-all-the-links | cargo run`.
When I do this, I get output like

```
link to: #
link to: https://stackoverflow.com
link to: #
link to: /teams/customers
...
```

```rust
extern crate html5ever;

use std::default::Default;
use std::io;

use html5ever::tendril::*;
use html5ever::tokenizer::BufferQueue;
use html5ever::tokenizer::{StartTag, TagToken};
use html5ever::tokenizer::{Token, TokenSink, TokenSinkResult, Tokenizer, TokenizerOpts,};
use html5ever::interface::QualName;
use html5ever::{ns, namespace_url, LocalName};

#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
struct TokenPrinter {}

impl TokenSink for TokenPrinter {
    type Handle = ();

    fn process_token(&mut self, token: Token, _line_number: u64) -> TokenSinkResult<()> {
        let link_name = QualName::new(
            None,
            ns!(),
            LocalName::from("href"),
        );
        match token {
            TagToken(tag) => {
                if tag.kind == StartTag && tag.name.to_string()=="a" {
                    let attrs = tag.attrs;
                    for attr in attrs {
                        if attr.name == link_name {
                            println!("link to: {}", attr.value);
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            _ => {
            },
        }
        TokenSinkResult::Continue
    }
}

fn main() {
    let sink = TokenPrinter {};
    let mut chunk = ByteTendril::new();
    io::stdin().read_to_tendril(&mut chunk).unwrap();
    let mut input = BufferQueue::new();
    input.push_back(chunk.try_reinterpret::<fmt::UTF8>().unwrap());

    let mut tok = Tokenizer::new(
        sink,
        TokenizerOpts::default(),
    );
    let _ = tok.feed(&mut input);
    assert!(input.is_empty());
    tok.end();
}
```